# Probability of dies of 2 green face and 4 red face

Tags: probability

A die that has 2 green faces and 4 red faces is rolled 3 times.

(4/6)*(4/6)*(4/6) is the chance of the event [pick all options that are correct]

“all the rolls show the same color”?

“not all the rolls show red”?

“none of the rolls shows red”?

“all the rolls show red”?

“not all the rolls show green”?

“none of the rolls shows green”?

my attempt:

all show same color;

all show red;

none show green;

"not all show green" is most likely NOT considered correct since it implies some are??wrong?  helpWay Forward on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just

1. All show red
2. none show green

because all show the same colour would be

$$
\frac{2}{6}\frac{2}{6}\frac{2}{6}+\frac{4}{6}\frac{4}{6}\frac{4}{6}
$$